# Rails Progressive Web Application problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to implement a progressive web application funtionality into my Rails 6 application, which works fine in first place. I'm developing an application for a hospital which should be accessible from outsite the hospital aswell, so we decided to redirect external requests in their DMZ to my webserver.

And that causes my problem: The script resource which is registering the service-worker is behind a redirect and can't access it, that's why the service worker doesn't get loaded and users can't use the functionality of a PWA.

Here's my code for registering the worker in application.js:

```
    if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', { scope: './' })
                           .then(function(registration) {
                             console.log('[Companion]', 'Service worker registered!')
                             console.log(registration)
                           })
}
```

Then I'm using the approach of two controllers, one for the manifest-file and the other for the service-worker which redirect to the according views / files.

In my head tag I added `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` in `application.html.erb`.

My routes are the following:

```
get '/service-worker.js', to: 'service_workers/workers#index'
get '/manifest.json', to: 'service_workers/manifests#index'
```

That's my service-worker.js:

```
var CACHE_VERSION = 'v1';
var CACHE_NAME = CACHE_VERSION + ':sw-cache-';

function onInstall(event) {
  console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Installing!", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function prefill(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '<%= asset_pack_path 'application.js' %>',
        '<%= root_path %>',
        '/mealplan',
      ]);
    })
  );
}

function onActivate(event) {
  console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Activating!", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.filter(function(cacheName) {
          // Return true if you want to remove this cache,
          // but remember that caches are shared across
          // the whole origin
          return cacheName.indexOf(CACHE_VERSION) !== 0;
        }).map(function(cacheName) {
          return caches.delete(cacheName);
        })
      );
    })
  );
}

// Borrowed from https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp
function onFetch(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    // try to return untouched request from network first
    fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
      // if it fails, try to return request from the cache
      return caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        // if not found in cache, return default offline content for navigate requests
        if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' ||
          (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
          console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Fetching offline content", event);
          return caches.match('/offline.html');
        }
      })
    })
  );
}

self.addEventListener('install', onInstall);
self.addEventListener('activate', onActivate);
self.addEventListener('fetch', onFetch);
```

The errors I get in the browser when accessing the application for external use are the following:

> The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xxxxxxx.nkbrf.de/') with script ('https://xxxxxxx.nkbrf.de/service-worker.js'): The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.

I think the scope property might be the problem, but I don't want to set it to a fixed value. Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I want to see the content of your file `service-worker.js`, maybe there is a error in this file.

Comment: Other thing, I think this is a litle mistake, but in your message: `Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xxxxxxx/service-worker.js') with script ('https://xxxxxx/service-worker.js')`, this `https://xxxxxxx/service-worker.js` is diferent of this `https://xxxxxxx/service-worker.js`. In the last URL is missing a character.

Comment: No I just didn't want to show the real URL, that's why I just deleted it and typed some 'x'-characters. The real URL is the same in both cases :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the scope property the error disappear? Do this test, because the scope property is optional and in your case, don't must be difference.

According to the Mozilla website:

> he scope parameter is optional, and can be used to specify the subset of your content that you want the service worker to control. In this case, we have specified '/sw-test/', which means all content under the app's origin. If you leave it out, it will default to this value anyway, but we specified it here for illustration purposes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: Mh indeed it seems if I delete the scope in my application.js it's working. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked a similar RoR problem found here:  [Drifting Ruby Example](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/progressive-web-applications).

To get the redirects to work (where I also can't use them), I had to make two alterations to the code provided in the sample listed above.

1. I had to get the value of "scope" inside of ruby (hence, index.json became index.json.erb), and I had to set the value to URI.join, `<%= response.headers["Service-Worker-Allowed"] = URI.join(request.original_url, "/").to_s %>"`

   2. Next I had to fully qualify the service-worker.js in routes.rb to be the full path of my workers file. `get "/service-worker.js", to: "xyz_abc/service_workers/workers#show"`
   3. Finally, I had to namespace and resource my two files within the parent resources: [routes.rb namespacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU9PE.png)

Those 3 steps got me through.